# How IP divides to point sub domains

Tags: dns, ip

I believe that default domain some `www.domain.com` points to some IP address `123.123.123.123` here when a sub domain is created which points to the same IP address. How the division of IP address works in real time to distribute IP to various sub domains. Do it uses port numbers to each sub domain? or any other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking how a webserver distinguishes between www.domain.com and something.domain.com when both are on the same ip address? It's done by the webserver - Apache uses `VirtualHost` configuration entries to distinguish based on a combination of IP address and the domain in the http URL.

You can read more about it here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: @JJ- Great answer. Well, will webserver create any configuration file to store this information? such that if I manually modify that file the values change.

Comment: Yes for Apache it is httpd.conf. You need to restart Apache after modifying the file.

Answer (score 1):

The root DNS server contains an entry called an NS record which indicates for each domain which server to query to resolve names in that domain. That server in turn may further redirect ("delegate") queries for individual subdomains. Read about the DNS e.g. at Wikipedia.